# React Context for changing language

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change context on the language that client is choose, but the the value of the context didn't change. What am I doing wrong?

This is the Context:

```
import React from 'react'

const LanguageContext = React.createContext({
    language: "EN",
    setLanguage: () => { }
})

export default LanguageContext
```

and this where I change language:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import LanguageContext from '../../Context'

const LanguageButton = () => {
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)
    const {language, setLanguage} = useContext(LanguageContext)

    const changeLanguage = () => {
        setIsClicked(!isClicked)
    }

    return (
        <span>
            <Span>
                <Button style={{ padding: 0 }} onClick={changeLanguage}>
                    Language - {language}
                </Button>
            </Span>
            {isClicked ?
                <Div style={{ position: 'absolute' }}>
                    <div><Button onClick={() => setLanguage('BG')} >BG - Bulgarian</Button></div>
                    <div><Button onClick={() => setLanguage('EN')}>EN - English</Button></div>
                </Div> : ''
            }
        </span>
    )
}
```

Comment: And what value should I set? Maybe use another state and use it's value for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no context provider in the component tree, the default value will be used, so `setLanguage` refers to `setLanguage: () => { }` which does nothing.

You'll need a component that actually stores the state, and then provides that to all subcomponents through the context:

```
 function WithLanguage({ children }) {
   const [language, setLanguage] = useState("");
   return <LanguageContext.Provider value={{ language, setLanguage }}>{ children }</LanguageContext.Provider>;
 }

 /* in some top component*/
<WithLanguage>
   <LanguageButton />
 </WithLanguage>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the Context:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export const Context = React.createContext("english");

export default class LanguageContext extends Component {

state = {
    language: localStorage.getItem('currentLanguage') ? localStorage.getItem('currentLanguage') : "english",
    name: "adads",
};


componentDidMount() {
    console.log("state", this.state)
}

onLanguageChange = language => {
    console.log('come', language)
    this.setState({ language }, () => { localStorage.setItem('currentLanguage', language) });
};


render() {
    return (
        <Context.Provider
            value={{ ...this.state, onLanguageChange: this.onLanguageChange, }}
        >
            {this.props.children}
        </Context.Provider >
    )
}
}
```

**this is app.js file**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Routercontainer from './routercontainer';
import LanguageContext from './context/languageContext';
function App() {
return (

<LanguageContext>
  <Routercontainer />
</LanguageContext>

    );
 }

export default App;
```

**THis is const file**

```
export const GujaratiWords = {
language: 'ભાષા',
Totalpendingamount: "કુલ બાકી રકમ",
Totalwithdrawalamounts: "કુલ ઉપાડની રકમ",
Totalsalary: "કુલ પગાર",
  }


    export const EnglishWords = {

language: 'language',
Totalpendingamount: "Total pending amount",
Totalwithdrawalamounts: "Totalwithdrawal amounts",
Totalsalary: "Total salary",
Perdaysalary: "Perday salary",
Addedsalary: "Added salary",
date: "date",
amount: "amount",
reason: "reason",

  }
```

**this is test.js file**

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react'
        import { EnglishWords, GujaratiWords } from './const'
        import { Context } from './context/languageContext'

        export default class Test extends Component {
        render() {
          return (
           <Context.Consumer>
              {
                (value) => {
                    return <>

                        <select onChange={(event) => 
            value.onLanguageChange(event.target.value)} class="form-select" 
            aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option selected={value.language == 'english' ? true 
            : false} value="english">  english</option>
                            <option selected={value.language == 'gujarati' ? 
              true : false} value="gujarati">  Guajrati </option>
                        </select>

                        <h1>{value.language === 'english' ? EnglishWords.Totalpendingamount : GujaratiWords.Totalpendingamount}</h1>
                    </>

                }
            }

        </Context.Consumer>
    )
}
     }
```